# Using AD and GPO to turn off print and file sharing

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to start building, I believe a base GPO to lock down the machines that will be on the network.  How do I go about doing this.  The first thing I want to do is disable file and print sharing for each machine that joins the domain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to disable file and print
>   sharing for each machine

You could simply disable the **server** service with a group policy.

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\System Services

Can you provide more detail about what you want?  Do you just need to prevent people from creating shares?

If you don't give the users privileged access on the computer they use, then they won't be able to create shares.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more direction?  If not I'll figure out a way to get 'er working.

Comment: If you disable the server service though you won't be able to do remote computer management that requires access to IPC$ or admin$ on the PCs.

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion - however, this will also disable the default c$ and admin$ shares

Comment: Which is something I'd rather not do...